# Get the list of the range of ips

Tags: linux, bash, ip, range

I need to get all the ips that belong to a range/CIDR. What command, script (bash), or utility can I use for this?

IMPORTANT: I need the print full list of ips addresses

Example:

```
192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255
or
192.168.0.0/24
```

Result:

```
 192.168.0.1
 192.168.0.2
 etc
 192.168.0.255
```

Or

```
192.168.0.1-192.168.255.255
or
192.168.0.0/16
```

Result

```
 192.168.0.1
 192.168.0.2
 etc
 192.168.255.255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `nmap` using the flag *-sL* you can list them. Then with the help of `grep` you can select only the output lines that contain and address.

Finally with cut we are selecting the 5th field of each line:

```
 nmap -sL -n 192.168.0.0/24 | grep 'Nmap scan report for' | cut -f 5 -d ' '
```

List all 255 addresses of /24

Or

```
nmap -sL -n 192.168.0.0-16| grep 'Nmap scan report for' | cut -f 5 -d ' '
```

from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.16

Comment: @acj I've just added it to the answer.

Comment: The range is missing (192.168.0.1-192.168.255.255)

Comment: nmap uses the format `192.168.0.0-16` to indicate from *192.168.0.0* to *192.168.0.16* as I've shown in my answer. It's a limitation of nmap.

Comment: OK does not matter. The answer is very good and solves the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Google to search for "IP Calculator"  or "Network Range Calculator"

You will get back a number of sites that, for free, can help you here.

For example:

1. http://jodies.de/ipcalc
2. http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Comment: nop. None of those sites gives me the list of 256 addresses that make up 192.168.0.0/24

Comment: The default page for http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ shows  192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254 which is a list of 254 host addresses in 192.168.0.0/24.  To 254, I add 1 (for 192.168.0.0 which is the address for the entire network) and 1 (for  192.168.0.255 which is the broadcast address). The result is 256 addresses.   I did not realize from your original post that you needed all of those IP addresses printed out.   I like using the free IP Calculators for this work.  The use of nmap by @jcbermu is also good.